# Capture Pause and cancel button event of Chrome download manager in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to capture the event whenever user cancel,pause stop or resume the download in chrome download manager using java script.
Googled a lot but didn't find any relevant information.
Thanks

Comment: Ajax calls (which are controlled by Javascript) do not show up in the download managers. As such, not possible.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Any work around or is it possible to capture same browser download events in IE

Comment: You can make your own download manager...

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Is it possible to create a chrome extension which can capture those events.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible.